# Importing css variables into root selector for theme

Tags: javascript, html, css, storybook, postcss

We have a theme engine based off style dictionary. The engine produces css files that have a `:root` element per theme - for instance:

```css
:root {
  --color-100: #161616;
  --color-90: #1e1e1e;
// ...
}
```

Each theme has a set of these them variables in separate files - so "alpha" theme is in a separate file, "beta" theme is in a separate file but each file structure is the same.

In a production build, the developers just include the css theme that is required, however, we are building a storybook instance that should be able to switch between all these themes.

We were planning to simply set a data property on the html when the theme changes:

```js
addons.getChannel().on(CURRENT_THEME, theme => {
  document.documentElement.setAttribute('theme', theme);
});
```

This works in the sense that the html tag changes to something like:

```html
<html lang="en" theme="alpha">
```

(where theme name is alpha).

In our styling our pseudo selectors are:

```css
:root[theme='alpha'] {
 // not sure what to put in here
}
```

The question is how to include each of the css files into a selector that would allow us to switch the data property to the new theme?

We have tried sass as well with `@import`/`@use` but haven't been able to get the theme css to load because there is no `mixin`.

We also have `postcss` available, but didn't find any plugin that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i got your question correctly, but you want too toggle the theme of your app so like if it is "alpha", let's say it follows red and black theme, if its "beta let's say it follows blue and black theme

So according to me what you can do is in your "alpha theme" css file you can give

```
:root[theme='alpha'] {
  --color-100: #red;
  --color-90: #black;
}
```

in beta you can give -

```
:root[theme='beta'] {
      --color-100: #blue;
      --color-90: #black;
    }
```

And in your some main css file which is having your application's element selectors, classes there you need to provide data as follows

```
p {
 color: var(--color-100);
}

button{
color: var(--color-200);
}
.header {
color: var(--color-200);
}
```

I hope you are getting what I am trying to say. Don't forget to import all your css modules.  Please let me know if it is not what you want :)

Comment: Thanks - but unfortunately not. Each theme file has `:root { ... }`  in it, not `:root[theme='alpha']`. I want to compose `:root[theme='alpha']` in the main css file by importing the contents into that selector.

Comment: So you are saying u have different theme css files and you want to have single css file? For all the themes?

Comment: Like you having theme alpha css, theme beta css and you want to have single theme file for alpha as well as beta? It that what you want

Comment: Yes, we have `alpha.theme.css` / `beta.theme.css` as files. In the real products, never will there be `alpha` mixed with `beta` (they are completely separated products) so it makes sense that the theme file contains _only_ the theme variables and you don't need to specify the theme - just include the css file you want. For documentation we want to be able to switch between each theme - hence the data attr to switch the css and importing each css file.